# Linq is producing unintended sql with left outer join

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have a linq statement thats supposed to produce a generic left outer join(specifically with nulls) but instead it produced a strange sql that also uses count(*)

This is the linq:

```
(from ccc in cDataContext.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings
 join cl in currentLogs on ccc.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID equals
 cl.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID 
 into final
 select final);
```

Current Logs looks like this:

```
 (from dll in cDataContext.DownloadLogs
  where dll.DTS.Hour == DateTime.Now.Hour && dll.DTS.Date== DateTime.Now.Date
  select dll)
```

The output sql becomes:

```
 SELECT [t1].[LogId], [t1].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID], [t1].[CaptureTime], [t1].[Response], [t1].[DTS], [t1].[DLID], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM clients.[dbo].[DownloadLog] AS [t2]
    WHERE ([t0].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID] = [t2].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID]) 
) AS [value]
FROM clients.[Store].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN clients.[dbo].[DownloadLog] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID] = [t1].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID])
ORDER BY [t0].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID], [t1].[LogId]
```

What im looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM 
clients.[Store].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings] AS [t0]
LEFT INNER JOIN clients.[dbo].[DownloadLog] AS [t1] 
ON ([t0].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID] = [t1].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID])
```

how do i produce the desired sql?

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has good linq examples. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/ee908647.aspx

For a Left Outer Join:

```
var q = 
    from c in categories 
    join p in products on c equals p.Category into ps 
    from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty() 
    select new { Category = c, ProductName = p == null ? "(No products)" : p.ProductName };
```

Comment: Looking for a left inner join

Comment: @Ukemi: The "What I'm looking for" section of your post says you are looking for a "left outer join".  Which is it?

Comment: @Ukemi: *Which* is your mistake? Are you looking for inner or for outer? Inner requires no special syntax, and the answer here provides the syntax for an outer join.